# How to connect to a localhost Rails site via mobile device locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile-phones, wifi

I have a Rails site that I'm developing on localhost Ubuntu and I have a mobile.
My site is running on http://localhost:3000.

I want to access this directly via my mobile browser not going through the internet.

Is there any way to access it via WiFi or some other way?

Answer (score 30):

If your computer is accessible from internet, just enter in your mobile browser:

```
http://your.ip:3000/
```

You could also create a local network (via wifi for instance), connect to it with your cell phone and then do the same thing.

If you are using Rails 4.2+, start the server using:

```
 rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

(see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server).

Comment: yeah and then you need like turn on the wi-fi on your phone. just saying. for some less intelligent of us, like me.

Answer (score 22):

1.) get your local ip by typing:

`ifconfig |grep inet`

into your shell/terminal. your ip usually looks like this: 192.xxx.xxx.xx

2.) then start the rails server with:

`rails server -b 0.0.0.0`

3.) your application can now be reached by typing:

`192.xxx.xxx.xx:3000` into the browser.

Comment: I would accept this answer. Worked just perfect. Now I can access rails server from my android device.

Answer (score 12):

Using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

So basically, you run the command

```
./ngrok http 3000
```

And you will see the output like that [image: ngrok output]

And all you need is copy the highlight URL and paste to the browser.

Answer (score 8):

Execute

```
rails s -b IP_ADDRESS
```

Access mobile: IP_ADDRESS:3000

Answer (score 4):

**On rails-server machine:**

- Make sure you're running rails-server.
- Get your IP address, I got "192.168.1.112" for example.

**On mobile:**

Access through browser by using:

```sh
http://<your_ip_address>:3000

http://192.168.1.112:3000
```

*NOTE: Your mobiles need to have the same network with rails-server machine.*

---

**To get yourself IP address, run this command in your rails-server machine.**

**MacOS or Linux Terminal:**

```sh
ipconfig getifaddr en0 || ipconfig getifaddr en1
# => 192.168.1.112
```

Description:

- `ipconfig getifaddr en0` is for wifi connections
- `ipconfig getifaddr en1` is for wired connections

**Windows:**

```sh
ipconfig
```

Then looking for `IPv4 Address`.

---

**Running rails-server**

On rails-server machine, it's okay to regularly run:

```sh
bin/rails s
```

If you found issue, you can try the following:

```sh
bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Note: `0.0.0.0` is not an IP address, it's a shortcut for the system binding call to use all available IP addresses including `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`.

Access through `http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score 3):

1. First find your Ip and note it down by typing ifconfig terminal(you should be connected to wifi or network)

> ifconfig

than run the rails server by typing

> rails server -b 0.0.0.0 (YOUR IP )

and press Enter
SERVER WILL BE RUNNING ON YOUR_IP:3000
2. Now connect your mobile with the same network and open url

> https://YOUR_IP:3000
>   **CONGRATS YOU ARE RUNNING LOCALHOST ON MOBILE**

Answer (score 2):

if you get **ipconfig command not found** on ubuntu
Try:
`ip route` to get the IP address then you can run rails server as explained in other answers.

`rails s -p 3000 -b 192.168.0.102` (Replace IP with your system's IP).

Now you should be able to access on you mobile browser by just entering
http://192.168.0.102:3000/

Answer (score 0):

- run your server on 0.0.0.0:port_no rather then 127.0.0.1 or localhost
- then check your IP address by typing a command in your terminal

  ipconfig
  [image]

  here you can check your host machine's IP address.

-Now we have to enable 3000 in your case port to be accessible in the network

write following commands

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw enable port_no
sudo ufw status
```

then you will be able to see your port is enabled

-Now you can access your server in any device browser using IP address:port_no

[image]

Check out this picture where I am accessing Django Web App running locally on Ubuntu and I am able to access it on my windows laptop which is in the same network via ip_addess:port_no which in my case is 8000

You can access the same website at